# JQGrid Header not align

Tags: jquery, html, css, jqgrid

I am using `4.4.4 - jQuery Grid` and `<= jquery 1.8.2` and here how I make my jqgrid

```
    function FAGrid() {
    var url1 = 'URL';
    $("#FAList").jqGrid({
        url: url1,
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'POST',
        colNames: ['rowId', 'FAID', 'Employee', 'Date<br/> Filed', 'Duration', 'Shift', 'ProjectSite', 'Contact Person', 'Purpose', 'Requested By', 'Approved By', 'Date Approved'],
        colModel: [
                    { name: 'rowId', index: 'rowId', hidden: true, width: 20 },
                    { name: 'FAID', index: 'FAID', hidden: true, editable: true, sortable: false, width: 20, align: 'center' },
                    { name: 'CompleteName', index: 'CompleteName', hidden: false, editable: true, sortable: false, width: 160, align: 'center' },
                    { name: 'FADateFiled', index: 'FADateFiled', hidden: false, editable: true, sortable: false, width: 52, align: 'center' },
                    { name: 'Duration', index: 'Duration', hidden: false, editable: true, sortable: false, width: 97, align: 'center' },
                    { name: 'ShiftDesc', index: 'ShiftDesc', editable: true, hidde: false, width: 75, align: 'center' },
                    { name: 'ProjectSite', index: 'ProjectSite', editable: true, sortable: false, width: 75, align: 'center' },
                    { name: 'FAContactPerson', index: 'FAContactPerson', editable: true, hidde: false, width: 75, align: 'center' },
                    { name: 'Purpose', index: 'Purpose', editable: true, sortable: false, width: 75, align: 'center' },
                    { name: 'FARequestedBy', index: 'FARequestedBy', editable: true, sortable: false, width: 115, align: 'center' },
                    { name: 'FAApprovedBy', index: 'FAApprovedBy', editable: true, sortable: false, width: 115, align: 'center' },
                     { name: 'FADateApproved', index: 'FADateApproved', editable: true, sortable: false, width: 75, align: 'center' }
                  ],
        pager: $('#FAPager'),
        rowNum: 5,
        rowList: [5, 10, 20],
        sortname: 'FADateFiled',
        sortorder: 'desc',
        viewrecords: true,
        imgpath: '/Content/themes/redmond/images/',
        height: '100%',
        loadComplete: function () {
            var ids = jQuery("#FAList").getDataIDs();
            var len = ids.length,
                newLine;
            if (len < 5) {
                AddNewRowToGrid(len, "#FAList");
            }
         }
    });
}
```

Here is the image. Even I change the width of the Name or any of the model it still the same not align. What is the problem?. CSS? JQgrid? or ?

[image]

Comment: is it possible to create a jsfiddle?

Comment: @AneeshSivaraman sorry i dont know how to use jsfiddle.

Comment: what are you trying to do in loadComplete?

Comment: @Yure: you will get more and more problems if you will stay using retro version 4.4.4. It's dead. It was created at the time of old jQuery, old jQuery UI and **old versions of web browsers**. The problem which you describe should not exist. **Please write always which web browser you used in the test**. Please make short test of the same JavaScript/HTML code with free jqGrid 4.14.4 (you need just temporary change three lines of HTML code. you need load jqGrid files from URLs described [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs)).

Comment: @Oleg if i change the jqgrid version and jquery version is there any functions / codes will not functioning to my current project?.

Comment: @Yure: the code which you posted should work without any problems. You can reduce the code essentually by removing many options. I posted you [the reference](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs). To verify whether you have do some minor compatibility problems you need just change 3 lines of HTML code to load `ui.jqgrid.css` from https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/free-jqgrid/4.13.4/css/ui.jqgrid.min.cs and so on.

Comment: @Oleg URL not found. And thanks for the help.

Comment: @Yure: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/free-jqgrid/4.13.4/css/ui.jqgrid.min.css (the last characters are `.css` instead of `.cs`). I posted you [the reference](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs) to the wiki article, where you can find URLs to all other CDN files. You can see in [the readme](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/README.md) [the link](http://www.jsdelivr.com/?query=free-jqgrid), [this one](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/free-jqgrid), [npm link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/free-jqgrid) and other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a local sample by adding some values. In my case it is working fine. Actually what are you trying to do in `loadComplete`? I have commented the loadComplete function.

The following is my code.

**HTML**

```
<table id="FAList"></table>
<div id="FAPager"></div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var data = [
{ rowId: "1",   FAID: "2",  CompleteName: "Emp name",   FADateFiled: "08/18/2016",  Duration: "3",  ShiftDesc: "Desc",  ProjectSite: "Site",    FAContactPerson: "Contact Person",  Purpose: "Purpose", FARequestedBy: "Requester", FAApprovedBy: "Approver",   FADateApproved: "08/18/2016"
},
{ rowId: "1",   FAID: "2",  CompleteName: "Emp name1",  FADateFiled: "08/18/2016",  Duration: "3",  ShiftDesc: "Desc1", ProjectSite: "Site1",   FAContactPerson: "Contact Person1", Purpose: "Purpose1",    FARequestedBy: "Requester1",    FAApprovedBy: "Approver1",  FADateApproved: "08/18/2016"
} 
];

function FAGrid() {

    var url1 = 'URL';
    $("#FAList").jqGrid({
        //url: url1,
        //datatype: 'json',
        datatype: 'local',
        //mtype: 'POST',
        colNames: ['rowId', 'FAID', 'Employee', 'Date<br/> Filed', 'Duration', 'Shift', 'ProjectSite', 'Contact Person', 'Purpose', 'Requested By', 'Approved By', 'Date Approved'],
        colModel: [
                    { name: 'rowId', index: 'rowId', hidden: true, width: 20 },
                    { name: 'FAID', index: 'FAID', hidden: true, editable: true, sortable: false, width: 20, align: 'center' },
                    { name: 'CompleteName', index: 'CompleteName', hidden: false, editable: true, sortable: false, width: 160, align: 'center' },
                    { name: 'FADateFiled', index: 'FADateFiled', hidden: false, editable: true, sortable: false, width: 52, align: 'center' },
                    { name: 'Duration', index: 'Duration', hidden: false, editable: true, sortable: false, width: 97, align: 'center' },
                    { name: 'ShiftDesc', index: 'ShiftDesc', editable: true, hidde: false, width: 75, align: 'center' },
                    { name: 'ProjectSite', index: 'ProjectSite', editable: true, sortable: false, width: 75, align: 'center' },
                    { name: 'FAContactPerson', index: 'FAContactPerson', editable: true, hidde: false, width: 75, align: 'center' },
                    { name: 'Purpose', index: 'Purpose', editable: true, sortable: false, width: 75, align: 'center' },
                    { name: 'FARequestedBy', index: 'FARequestedBy', editable: true, sortable: false, width: 115, align: 'center' },
                    { name: 'FAApprovedBy', index: 'FAApprovedBy', editable: true, sortable: false, width: 115, align: 'center' },
                     { name: 'FADateApproved', index: 'FADateApproved', editable: true, sortable: false, width: 75, align: 'center' }
                  ],
        pager: $('#FAPager'),
        rowNum: 5,
        rowList: [5, 10, 20],
        sortname: 'FADateFiled',
        sortorder: 'desc',
        viewrecords: true,
        //imgpath: '/Content/themes/redmond/images/',
        height: '100%',
        /*loadComplete: function () {
           debugger;
           var ids = jQuery("#FAList").getDataIDs();
           var len = ids.length,
           newLine;
           //if (len < 5) {
           //    AddNewRowToGrid(len, "#FAList");
           //}
        }*/
    });
    $("#FAList")[0].addJSONData({
            total: 1,
            page: 1,
            records: data.length,
            rows: data
        });    

    }

    FAGrid();

 });
```

Please check this [`Fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/yNw3C/14507/) for reference

Answer (score 0):

try to give the items in your colModel a attribute `fixed: true`